# How to work with mailchimp templates using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailchimp, gibbon

I'd like to work with mailchimp templetes with Ruby.
I installed gem mailchimp-api and tried this:

```
mailchimp = Mailchimp::API.new(ENV['MAILCHIMP_API_KEY'])
lists = mailchimp.templates.list
list  = lists['data']
puts list
```

It returns `lists = Hash (3 elements): 'user'= Empty Array, 'gallery'= Empty Array, 'base'= Empty Array`, and as the result `list = nil`.

I installed gem gibbon and tried this:

```
gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key: ENV['MAILCHIMP_API_KEY'])
templates =  gibbon.templates.retrieve(params: {type: 'user'})
templates['templates'].each do |template|
  if template['name'] == 'my_template'
    id = template['id']
```

I get the template id, but `gibbon.templates.info(template_id: id)` returns # with `@api_endpoint=nil`. How can I recieve the template source and used it?

Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Mailchimp account can be linked with mandrill account to send transactional mails. The solution is to clone template from mailchimp to mandrill and use mandrill-api gem to load template body, like this:

```
 mandrill = Mandrill::API.new(ENV["SMTP_PASSWORD"])
 body = mandrill.templates.render(template_name, [], vars )["html"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly but maybe you should use `retrieve` to find template by id.
Something like

```
gibbon.templates.retrieve(params: { template_id: your_id_here })
```

According to [official docs](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/templates/#read-get_templates_template_id).

Comment: It returns first 10 templates from the all of templates(

Comment: and what about `gibbon.templates(your_id_here).retrieve`?

Comment: Sure it works fine, but this is the same as `template` in my loop `templates['templates'].each` when `if template['name'] == 'my_template'` returns `true`.  I didn't find examples about how to use templates with Ruby.

Comment: I mean example about how to work with template source and so on.

Comment: Try to debug [this](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-ruby/src/37dbe82057b96e135881c9379c0a3d5f8f32bf1f/lib/mailchimp.rb?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#mailchimp.rb-41) place. You need to see what `r.body` contains. That is what your `lists` is equal to.

Comment: I found the solution. Mailchimp account can be linked with mandrill account to send transactional mails. The solution is to clone template from mailchimp to mandrill and use mandrill-api gem to load template body, like this:
`def mandrill_template(template_name, attributes)
    mandrill = Mandrill::API.new(ENV["SMTP_PASSWORD"])
    mandrill.templates.render(template_name, [], merge_vars)["html"]
 end'

Comment: Congrats! But this seems like too mush workaround)) I recommend you to debug source code if will have vacant time